# can't seem to get merge or joins to work in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I seem to be having some issues around joining/merging in pandas.  (I've never had this issue until now.)  So, right now I have this code so far:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc

conn_str = (
            r'Driver={SQL Server};'
            r'Server=fake.fake.lan;'
            r'Database=fake;'
            r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
            )

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

attr = pd.read_excel('AttrList.xlsx')

attr['PATIENT NAME1'] = attr['LAST_NAME'] + ', ' + attr['FIRST_NAME']

sql = '''SELECT  ssn.Client_ID, 
        ssn.SSN,
        n.LastName + ', ' + n.FirstName AS clientname
FROM    limiteddb.dbo.Client_SSN AS ssn
        INNER JOIN limiteddb.dbo.ClientName AS n ON n.Client_ID = ssn.Client_ID
                                             AND n.ORG_ID = 1;'''

data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn))
```

Now at this point I have 2 dataframes I would like to merge together based on SSN. (Both have an SSN column)  But for whatever reason, I can't seem to make it work.

I've tried the below but when I call merged, my two SSN columns aren't matching.  (For example i'll have SSN1 be 485358751 and SSN2 be 952147652 for row 1.  All my examples are fake.)  None of the two SSNs seem to matching on each other:

```
merged = attr.join(data, lsuffix='1', rsuffix='2')`
```

I've also tried merge but I wind up with NaN values for pretty much the entirety of my data:

```
merged = pd.merge(attr, data, on='SSN', how='outer')
```

I've looked at the data in Excel and when I look at matches there I know that roughly 90% of my data should have matched SSNs.  I've also checked my data types.  Any suggestions/ideas/help are appreciated.

EDIT: for anyone wondering, i've the obvious Joins/merges.  I know how to do them. I'm not sure what's causing this, but for some reason my two dataframes don't realize that they share a LOT of SSNs.  When I do an inner join, my dataframe is empty for example.  I've checked to make sure both of my SSNs are objects.  `attr['SSN'] = attr['SSN'].astype(object)`

EDIT:Here are the printed datatypes for my 2 dataframes once they are imported.

attr:

LAST_NAME                         object
FIRST_NAME                        object
ALTRUISTA_ID                       int64
PATIENT_DOB                       object
RISK_CATEGORY_NAME                object
RISK_SCORE                       float64
HEALTH PLAN                       object
THL_STATUS                        object
ASSIGNED DATE/ATTRIBUTED DATE     object
ADDRESS                           object
PHONE NUMBER                     float64
INSURANCE ID                     float64
SSN                                int64
PROGRAM_NAMES                     object
LAST_CLAIM                       float64
LAST_VISIT_DATE                  float64
NEXT_VISIT_DATE                  float64
PCP_NAME                          object
ER_VISITS                          int64
APP_VISITS                         int64
ADTDAYS_COUNT                      int64
DUE_DAYS                           int64
dtype: object

data:

Client_ID      int64
SSN           object
clientname    object
dtype: object

So at this point I need to cast my SSN from the attr dataframe to a string.  I have been using `attr['SSN'].apply(str)` to do this. (I was using `attr['SSN'] = attr['SSN'].astype(object)` but it wasn't working.  I'm thinking this was my initial problem.)  Here it shows the datatype has changed once I run this: SSN  object.  Now for my merge:  `merged = pd.merge(attr, data, on='SSN', how='outer')`.  It looks like it worked!

Comment: `.join` joins on index of both dataframes while `.merge` joins on specified column. Why not `how='inner'`, the default arg?

Answer (score 0):

`join` joins on indices by default, so unless you are using SSN as your DataFrame's index then the results won't match.  If you don't want to join on index, you can specify which column to join on with the `on` argument.  (It's also worth noting that `join` does a left join by default, which may or may not be what you want.)

`merge` with `how='outer'` will (by definition of outer join) give you `NaN`s if there are any rows in one DataFrame but not the other when matching on the specified keys.  So I would expect `NaN`s unless there is a perfect 1:1 mapping of SSNs between DataFrames.  Depending on what you are trying to do, would it make more sense to do an `inner` join?

Comment: I've tried both ways. I've tried setting SSN as the index for 1 df and for both while using join. I've also tried using on = ['SSN'] with it, but i'm still getting the wrong SSNs matching up in my rows.

With merge my entire dataframes are winding up as NaN.  The first dataframe (attr) has it's columns then the supposedly joined columns of dataframe2 (data) with NaNs.  Scroll down and then inverse appears.  All of attr's data is NaN and data's columns are populating.  

For whatever reason, it can't understand that there are SSNs that match between the two dataframes.